# Click listener incorrect data after resizing window with canvas in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, html5-canvas

I am using a canvas with clickable elements that was added using for loop, I added a resizing event that redrawing the canvas after user window was resized, When the window is loading for the first time the canvas and click listeners works great, My problem starts after the window resizing, I getting wrong click coordinates and bad behavior, It looks the click event have sort of a backlog for all the times that the screen was resized

Here is the full code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r3g1y8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

The resize function

```
   @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
    onResize(event) {
      this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
      this.innerHeight = window.innerHeight;
      this.canvas.width = this.innerWidth;
      this.canvas.height = this.innerHeight 
      this.cleardraw()
      this.draw()         
    }

      cleardraw(){
    var ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.innerWidth, this.innerHeight);

   }
```

The draw function

```
draw() {

  var ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.font = "15px Arial";
  var seats = []                               
  var tempOrderArrey = []                        
  var orderSeatsClinet = []                        
  var selectedSeatsClient = []                      
  var numberOfSeats = 10
  var numberOfRows = 10
  var canvasWidth = this.innerWidth
  var canvasHight = this.innerHeight


  function Seat(x, y, w, h, id, line, seatNum, color) {
      this.x = x - 160
      this.y = y ;
      this.w = w;
      this.h = h;
      this.id = id;
      this.line = line
      this.seatNo = seatNum + 1 ;
      this.color = color
  }


  Seat.prototype.draw = function () {
      ctx.fillStyle = this.color
      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h)


  }



  function drawAll() {
      for (var i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
          seats[i].draw();
      }
  }

    var id = 1;
    var xPad = canvasWidth / 30


    function addSeats(value, ch) {
        for (let i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
            seats.push(new Seat( (canvasWidth / 3) + (i * xPad), value, canvasWidth/ 37, canvasWidth/ 37, id++, ch, i, "#998515"));
    }

    var start = 60, diff = canvasWidth/30, ch = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        //60 + (40 * i)
        addSeats(start + (diff * i), ch++);
    }     

  drawAll()
```

The click event function

```
 this.renderer.listen(this.canvasRef.nativeElement, 'click', (event) => {
    let cX = event.layerX;
    let cY = event.layerY;

    const offsetLeft = this.canvasRef.nativeElement.offsetLeft;
    const offsetTop = this.canvasRef.nativeElement.offsetTop;

    this.cX = cX - offsetLeft;
    this.cY = cY - offsetTop;

      for (var i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
          var s = seats[i];
          if (cX >= s.x && cX < s.x + s.w && cY >= s.y && cY < s.y + s.h) {
              if (s.color == '#998515') {      // If green
                  tempOrderArrey.push({ "id": s.id, "seatNum": s.seatNo, "rowNum": s.line })
                  s.color = '#ff0000'
                  ctx.fillStyle = '#ff0000'
                  ctx.fillRect(s.x, s.y, s.w, s.h)

              }
              else if (s.color == '#ff0000') {  // If red
                  tempOrderArrey = tempOrderArrey.filter(seat => seat.id != s.id);
                  ctx.fillStyle = '#998515'
                  s.color = '#998515'
                  ctx.fillRect(s.x, s.y, s.w, s.h)                                   
              }

          }
          this.tempOrderArrey =   tempOrderArrey
      }})



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that each time you resize, `renderer.listen` is called again, so for one click there are many events being fired.

You need to make sure that you clear the listener before creating a new one

```
// Check if the reference exists
if (this.reference != null) {
    this.reference; // Clear the listener
}

// Store a reference to the listener
this.reference = this.renderer.listen(this.canvasRef.nativeElement, 'click', (event) => {
```

**[Here is a fork of the StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-67dhah?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Is there any easy method to keep the color of the rectangle after it was clicked?

Comment: You need to maintain the color state for each seat. That said, there are far simpler ways to do this rather than using canvas

Comment: Yes I am sure, but i need to use a canvas for this project. Any way I used a temp arrey that saves all the selections . Thank you